# Antiderivative of little o

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives, proof-writing, asymptotics

This question has already been asked but non of the answers I found were correct/thorough enough.

For $x$ near zero and $n>1$, is the antiderivative of $o(x^n)$ equal to $o( x^{n+1} )$ and how do we prove it?

Little $o$ is defined as:

> $f$ is $o( g )$ near zero if and only if there is a function $u$ that tends to zero when $x$ nears zero and satisfies $f = u g,$ or for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists some $a>0$ such that $∣ f(x)∣ \leq \epsilon |g(x)|$ whenever $0< |x| <a$

I used both definitions but couldn't get anywhere, integration by parts also didn't help, I know that it is not true for the derivative that: the derivative of $o(x^n)$ equal to $o( x^{n-1} )$ but I'm not sure about integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's no trouble with this, the key point is that integration preserves inequalities (which is very false for differentiation); that is, if $f(x) \le g(x)$ then $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx \le \int_a^b g(x) \, dx$.

More formally, if $f(x) = o(|x|^n)$, then by definition we have that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |x| < \delta$ then $|f(x)| < \epsilon |x^n|$. Define

$$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt.$$

Then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |x| < \delta$ then $|f(x)| < \epsilon (n+1) |x^n|$, hence such that

$$|F(x)| = \left| \int_0^x f(t) \, dt \right| \le \int_0^x |f(t)| \, dt \le \int_0^x \varepsilon (n+1) |t|^n \, dt = \varepsilon |x|^{n+1}.$$

So $F(x) = o(|x|^{n+1})$. We didn't really need to insert the $n+1$ prefactor but it's nice to make the final bound come out to exactly what it needs to be.

Comment: wow thank you so much!! this was super helpful